# Rendering perfect spheres and ellipsoids in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, pipeline, render

Let's say I want to render a perfect sphere or ellipsoid in Unity 3D - one with a centre point and one or two radii, rather than a mesh. How would I need to go about this? Would I need to make a custom render pipeline, or is there a way to accomplish it with shaders?

The reason I ask is that I'd like to replicate the style of the classic adventure game Ecstatica, which combines both traditional 3D objects and mathematical ellipsoids. To get maximum effect the ellipses have to be super-smooth and intersect each other perfectly. They also have to intersect with regular polygonal meshes.

n.b. I'm not asking for complex mathematics at the moment, I can probably accomplish that myself, I'm just wondering what my starting point should be?

Answer (score 0):

WHY is it that whenever I post a question here after searching extensively for an answer, about seven times in ten I then almost immediately find that answer? So embarrassing...

Nevertheless, I DID find an answer - and it's such a good solution that I wanted to share it:

https://bgolus.medium.com/rendering-a-sphere-on-a-quad-13c92025570c#bac5